# how to print output simultaneously in Python

Tags: python

```
print "Trying to connect VM "
try:
    ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect('hostname',username='abc',password='1234')
    print ("Connected \n")
    command1='cd '+ PATH + " ; ls -ltr %s/abc.bin | awk '{print $9}' | cut -d '/' -f 8 | xargs grid -h " + MACHINE_TYPE + " -f "
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command1)
    for line in stdout:
        print line
    except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
       print ("failed to connect \n")
       sys.exit(1)
       ssh.close()
```

Here stdout is a huge output where it will be printing continuously around 600  lines.Until  `ssh.exec_command(command1)` this completes i won't be able to print stdout. I am looking for simultaneous output on console too...Any help would be great!

Comment: The thing is, until `exec_command` completes *no other code that could print something will even run*. I'm not sure what else you'd be wanting to print in the meantime…!?

Comment: you can bring stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command1)
    for line in stdout: inside a loop or delay it using sleep commands.

Comment: Try to run the code that prints in a side process, so the rest of the code will run at the same time that you print to the screen, as far as I know, there is no way to print more than one thing at the same time.

Comment: @deceze : While Running this command (exec_command) ,i am unable to see the output on IDLE console.since output is getting stored on stdout.